# Symbols of Borgman

Tags: analysis, borgman

I've read that [Borgman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borgman_%28film%29) is full of Biblical symbols. Not being well educated in this area, I am looking for someone to explain the symbols appearing in Borgman to me.

Answer (score 1):

The lead character is called Camiel. That is the name of one of the Archangels. His surname is Borgman, which means something akin to landlord or toll taker.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the movie yesterday for the first time and I think I found a quite concise interpretation. I think it's a modern time adaption of elf/troll stories. Especially as they are represented in the ancient alpine legends and mythology.

One of the key moments for this view is the scenes when he sits on the sleeping persons causing nightmares. This is exactly what the "Alben" in German/Austrian myths are doing (maybe also in Nordic tales, I don't know about that).

Then everything fits together. They live below the surface/underground. They can be useful and helpful but quite often they also cause much harm, especially when you don't treat them right. Not treating right can mean, interestingly, also beeing too kind to them. But also too unkind of course.

Then they for instance kidnap children take them away and educate them as to get also such demon-like creatures. The German Rumpelstilzchen fairy tale also reflects in part some of these aspects.

At times they approach people and ask for something, like the bath.

Also the intro scene matches this quite well. Priests have always fought these kinds of "spirits" or goblins. And some, possibly silver lance might be a quite appropriate tool to fight them.

Also the scene when they trick the people to make Borgman become the gardener, that is typical "gnome/sprite/goblin" wit.

Instead of magics they use mobile phones to communicate. But in part they show also supernatural powers. And also they sing and dance. So this is what I consider "modern time adaption" of gnome myths.

So all in all, I don't think it's not mystery it's much more a modern day fantasy adaption.